# how to call windows paint event from child thread

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

If I am wrong then please correct me as I am new in this. I have one thread which display image captured from webcam on a windows created using `CreateWindowEx()` function. Now when i execute my program I can see that my paint code (in `WindowProc()`) in never reached (called `InvalidateRect()` from child thread to redraw), checked using breakpoint.

Actually frame capture and display is being done in thread and I think because its in `child thread` and `Window` is in `Main thread` that is why its not able to call paint event.

Can you help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `InvalidateRect()` from a child thread should make your window redraw. However `WM_PAINT` is a low priority message, so it is possible that the window doesn't get redrawn if there is too much other activity. Have you tried putting a Sleep() into you processing thread to give the painting a chance to get done?